# Maximum MTU size

Tags: ping, mtu

Thought one of the issues I'm experiencing with the following question is due to MTU rightfully so.
[ESXi 5 VM Putty session hangs, vSphere client timing out](https://serverfault.com/questions/553954/esxi-5-vm-putty-session-hangs-vsphere-client-timing-out)

However, when I tried testing the maximum MTU size it seems there's just no limit.  Thought Ethernet only allows maximum MTU.  But I'm up to 54450.
ping -l 54450 192.168.10.7

Pinging 192.168.50.7 with 54450 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.10.7: bytes=54450 time=1081ms TTL=62
Reply from 192.168.10.7: bytes=54450 time=1079ms TTL=62
Reply from 192.168.10.7: bytes=54450 time=1079ms TTL=62
Reply from 192.168.10.7: bytes=54450 time=1079ms TTL=62

Ping statistics for 192.168.10.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1079ms, Maximum = 1081ms, Average = 1079ms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the -f switch so that the packets will not be fragmented.

Comment: Thanks!  I found out with this the MTU is 1363 bytes.  Have set the MTU to 1200 as per http://my.bergersoft.net/2010/05/13/how-to-change-mtu-size-on-windows-xpvista72008/.  Thanks you saved me!